# Matching Zero Using Regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

How  to do the following using `Regex`

```
String Str="11111111";
if(Str.Contains("0"))
         MessageBox.Show("Not matching");
else
         MessageBox.Show("Matching");
```

Is this Pattern correct `Regex rx=new Regex("0*");` ?

```
Mathc mh=rx.Match(Str);

if(mh.Success==false)
         MessageBox.Show("Not matching");
else
         MessageBox.Show("Matching");
```

But its not working. My string `Str` does not have `0` but its showing `mh.Success=true`

Please help me

Comment: I should mention that using a regex to detect `0` in a string is akin to trying to kill a mosquito with a thermo-nuclear warhead. I would hope that this is just sample/play code.

Comment: Yes... it is... but its just for learning

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The asterisk (*) means 0 or more occurences, what you want is just to find a single occurence anywhere, so simply "0" would do, i.e:

```
Regex ex = new Regex("0");
```

Answer (score 3):

The regular expression `0*` refers to zero or more `0`s. That's the reason the match is a success. As Aviad P. says, just the expression `0` would do. Alternatively, you could use an expression such as `^[^0]*$` as a test expression that must match the *entire* string. Of course, there's no reason to use regex here when a simple `string.Contains`does the job.